# Serialize a protoBuf-net message to a stream c# - getting error "Only data-contract classes can be processed"

Tags: c#, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I have a message in protoBuf which called "package", I generated my .proto file to classes in purpose to fill all the required fields in that "package" and it works fine.
Now, I have that protoBuf message instance called "package" and I want to serialize it to a stream and then output it to a file.

```
                    byte[] data;
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        Serializer.Serialize<repo_package.Package.Builder>(ms, package);
                        data = ms.ToArray();
                    }
                    string packageFilePath = Path.Combine("C:\\1", package.Name);
                    File.WriteAllBytes(packageFilePath, data);
```

The problem is the I'm getting an Error when I calling to "Serializer" function, the error is

"Only data-contract classes (and lists/arrays of such) can be processed"

Why is that?
How I can output my Package (protobuf message) to a file?

Thank you,

Orion.

Comment: Likely the problem is that you haven't decorated the class with the proper attributes... ex: [ProtoContract] and [ProtoMember(1)]...

Comment: Can you show anything about `Builder` ? Note that further to @jsobo's comment - there are other ways to configure the model that don't require *attributes*, but the key point is that *somehow* you need to configure the system. The simplest way to do that is attributes, but you can also use runtime code to tell it what you want it to do.

Comment: @jsobo where I need to add the decorations?

Comment: @Marc_Gravell, the generated .cs file from the .proto file is huge and not all the code there is understandable.

Comment: @Orionlk right; you have a file generated from .proto - that's a good start. Now: what tool did you use to do that code-gen? If it was the protobuf-net tool, then it *should work*. I would be very interested to hear that it isn't. So: what too did you use to turn the .proto into .cs ? I have a *suspicion* that maybe you've used the tooling from Jon's implementation, but my library.

Comment: Hi @Orionlk - it looks like you added an answer with more detail and then deleted it - since you deleted it, I'm not sure what the current state is - do you need further assistance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a library cross-over; if your DTO is `Package`, then the existence of `Package.Builder` strongly suggests that you are using the code-generation tools from Jon Skeet's `protobuf-csharp-port` implementation. That is fine, but code generated via `protobuf-csharp-port` expect to be used *with* the `protobuf-csharp-port` library, which probably means "use the `WriteTo` method on the DTO instance".

`protobuf-net` is a completely separate implementation of the same serialization protocol; it has *separate* code-generation tools (admittedly it may be slightly confusing that both involve tools called `protogen` and `protoc`). If you use the `protobuf-net` version of `protogen`, it will output code that works with the `protobuf-net` library (for completeness, with `protobuf-net` it is also common to use code-first, without ever involving a `.proto` file, but contract-first `.proto` usage is fully supported).

So; either:

- stick with the `protobuf-csharp-port` code-generation, and switch to the `protobuf-csharp-port` runtime, or:
- stick with the `protobuf-net` runtime, and switch to the `protobuf-net` code-generation

Comment: Thank you @Marc_Gravell, I understand my mistake, I stick with protobuf-net instance and function and now its works just fine.